# Stopping default deselect on click of map OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to create a box selection where I don't want to unselect until I click on an action button.
Right now its getting unselected as soon as I click somewhere on points or anywhere on the map. Also, at the same time select and unselect gets propagated which I tried to stop using option (remove condition, but ideally I am not adding any condition, so it won't work.)
here is my experimental [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-features-forked-7n2mc?file=/main.js)

1. I tried to stop event propagation on click of map after selection
   but didn't find it of any use as I exactly don't know which event to
   stop.
2. I also though of setting deselected points back to selection
   as an undo option. But no method to set into select.
3. And lastly in select I thought of option but no such option found.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: It is probably best done without using the Select interaction, as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-multiple-features.html

Comment: @TomazicM its not related to GIS SE I am asking about openlayers clearly mentioned in tags as well as my example code explains it click on code you will see the example.

Comment: GIS SE is short for this site: Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange. What I'm referring to pertains to all questions posted on this site. Links to external code tend to get lost in time, so all code relevant to the question should be included in the body of the question.

Comment: thanks for the help i'll try to do that .!

Comment: @Mike thank you for the answer i thing this will work for me !!